# How can I simulate the End chunk providing in the overworld in Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make a modpack, where the island you spawn on is the same type of island as in the end. Since I could not find any mods, I decided to make my own. I am having trouble though, making it spawn an island. I want it to use the same  style as the Surface, or Plains chunk generation, where there is grass, a few trees, but on an island. I have the game using this biome as a apposed to any other biome, but it is not an island. Someone told me that it is the `EndBiomeDecorator`, and I believe it is, but I cannot seem to get that to work in the overworld.

Comment: Uhm, I strongly suggest you start off simple. First inject a few custom trees, a couple of custom buildings into the worldgen. Then when you are a bit more familiar with the flow, you can look into your own worldgen... don't start out with the hardest part first...

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for you would be to make your island a "structure" and use the structure generator to generate your island.

That way you can shape the island to your peferences and at locations of your choosing.